# How to boot into the bootloader when you have ClockworkMod?

Tags: htc-desire, rom-flashing, fastboot, radio-firmware

I want to upgrade the radio and I'm not sure how to boot into `bootloader`.

When I try to power the phone using VolumeDown+Power, I do get into the ClockworkMod Recovery, but it seems that this is not what I was looking for because on PC the command `fastboot flash radio radio.img` is still `< waiting for device >`.

In case it matters, this is a permarooted + hroot + ClockworkMod, HTC Desire HD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Make sure your phone is powering off completely before you try to boot into the bootloader. For a DHD you might need to go into `Settings > Applications` and uncheck the "FastBoot" option in order for it to power down completely ([source](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=889567)).
2. If #1 doesn't help, try turning your phone off, then pulling the battery. After you've pulled the battery and waited a few seconds, hold the volume down button and put the battery back in the phone. Then continue to hold volume down while you power up the phone and it should land on the bootloader.
3. If #1 and #2 don't work (or you're lazy, since I think this is the easiest way), plug your phone into a computer that has `adb` on it. Make sure USB debugging is enabled, then simply enter `adb reboot bootloader` from an `adb` terminal. This will (unsurprisingly) reboot your phone into the bootloader.

Comment: #3 worked and it was by far the easiest method.

Answer (score 0):

Not with Galaxy xCover GT-S5690 Gingerbread XXLA6 ... adb reboot bootloader boot "normal". Also #2 boot normal. Volume down & power up boot into recover which is not bootloader "mode". Gobbling thing.

Comment: This question is about an HTC Desire HD and not a Samsung.